# How can these regular expressions be written more concisely?

Tags: regex

Can I combine these regular expressions somehow?:

```
        _regexes = new List<Regex>();
        _regexes.Add(new Regex("[0-9]*th Fl$"));
        _regexes.Add(new Regex("[0-9]*th Floor$"));
        _regexes.Add(new Regex("[0-9]*st Fl$"));
        _regexes.Add(new Regex("[0-9]*st Floor$"));
        _regexes.Add(new Regex("[0-9]*nd Fl$"));
        _regexes.Add(new Regex("[0-9]*nd Floor$"));
        _regexes.Add(new Regex("[0-9]*rd Flr$"));
        _regexes.Add(new Regex("[0-9]*rd Floor$"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\d+(?:st|th|nd|rd) Fl(?:r|oor)?$
```

- Match at least a digit or more, not zero digits (which is probably a shortcoming in the original)
- Don't forget `st`
- Match `Fl`, `Floor` or `Flr`
- Use non-capturing group `(?:` instead of capturing group
- Assumes perl compatible regex

Answer (score 1):

```
[0-9]*(st|th|nd|rd) (Fl|Floor)$
```

should have the same effect. Using the `|` operator you actually say you want one of the possibilities.

[assuming `_regexes.Add(new Regex("[0-9]*rd Flr$"));` - the r is a typo] is it?

Comment: This is incorrect. It fails to match, e.g. "1st Floor" or "2nd Fl".

Comment: it needs a space `\s` -> `[0-9]*(st|th|nd|rd)\s(Fl|Floor)$`

Comment: Yea, it was a typo - I editted and added it. It needs a specific `' '`, not `\s`. [the original doesn't accept TAB for instance] Thanks @Robbie